# change target in gameobject instance clone per script c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and C#, and hopefully you can help me with a problem. I cant find the solution online.

[image: Seeker Inspector, see Target]

I'm working on a pathfinding tutorial I found on youtube. I want to change the target in my seeker clone from another script. I can change the speed with:

```
obj.GetComponent<Unit> ().Speed =20;
```

That works well, but I don't know how to change the target. I can change the target manually at runtime by drag and drop another target on the inspector field from my assets. How can I do the same action with code from another script?

I tried it with:

```
obj.GetComponent<Unit> ().Target = John (UnityEngine.Transform);
```

but I get this error:

> Assets/Scripts/spawner.cs(23,38): error CS0103: The name `John' does not exist in the current context

and

> Assets/Scripts/spawner.cs(23,57): error CS0119: Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'method group' was expected

When I'm asking for:

```
Debug.Log (obj.GetComponent<Unit> ().Target  );
```

I get this:

> Peter (UnityEngine.Transform)
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   spawner:FixedUpdate() (at Assets/Scripts/spawner.cs:24)

Can you help me with the right syntax please?

my script is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform spawnPos;
    public GameObject spawnee;
    GameObject obj;
    GameObject objt;    

    void Update () {        

        if((Input.GetKey (KeyCode.G))) {
            Instantiate(spawnee, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
        }       
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if((Input.GetKey (KeyCode.H))) {
        obj = GameObject.Find ("Seeker(Clone)");
        obj.GetComponent<Unit> ().Speed =20;
        obj.GetComponent<Unit> ().Target = John (UnityEngine.GameObject);
        Debug.Log (obj.GetComponent<Unit> ().Target  );
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You want to set a `Transform` reference there. What is `John` supposed to be? The object you instantiated before on pressing `G`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your code correctly you are trying to instatiate a new Object and set `Target` to this new objects `Transform` component.

In your code you have also another mistake I'ld say:

[`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) fires constantly **every frame** while the key is pressed! I think you rather want to use [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) so it is fired only once per click.

Then I'ld advice you to never call something like `Find` or `GetComponent` in any `Update` method. They are quite expensive. Better add additional variables to store those references once and reuse them later.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Transform spawnPos;
    public GameObject spawnee;

    private GameObject obj;
    // private GameObject objt;    

    // here we store and re-use the Unit component reference
    Unit unit;

    // You need an additional variable for the Object you instantiate
    GameObject lastInstantiatedObject;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // do those expensive methods already and only once in the beginning
        obj = GameObject.Find ("Seeker(Clone)");
        unit = obj.GetComponent<Unit>();
    }


    private void Update () {        

        // use GetKeyDown to fire only once per click
        if((Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.G))) 
        {
            // store a reference to the instaiated object so you can access it later
            lastInstantiatedObject = Instantiate(spawnee, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
        }       
    }

    privte void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        if((Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.H))) 
        {
            // unit was set already in Awake so we can reuse the reference
            // anyway just in case the object was not there yet while Awake
            // add a little check
            if(!unit)
            {
                Awake();
            }

            // if unit is still not set you have an error and should not go ahead
            if(!unit)
            {
                Debug.LogError("For some reason unit could not be set!", this);
                return;
            }

            unit.Speed =20;

            // Before going on you should add a similar check for the lastInstantiatedObject variable
            if(!lastInstantiatedObject)
            {
                Debug.LogError("No object instanitated so far or it was destroyed again!", this);
                return;
            }

            // Target is of type Transform
            // Usually to get a component you would have to call
            // lastInstantiatedObject.GetComponent<TypeOfComponent>()
            // but Trasnform is an exception. Since every GameObject has a Transform
            // component, you can use the shortcut lastInstantiatedObject.transform
            unit.Target = lastInstantiatedObject.transform;

            Debug.Log (unit.Target);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Target` variable is a type of [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) and you want to change it via script during run-time.

According to your screenshot, you have a GameObject named "John" and another one name "Peter" which is not shown in  the screenshot but in the code. You are looking for the [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) function. Find the the Peter or John Object, get the `transform` then assign it to the `Target`. This is easier than you thought.

---

Your target

```
public Transform Target;
```

Find the Peter and John GameObjects:

```
GameObject peterObject = GameObject.Find("Peter");
GameObject johnObject = GameObject.Find("John");
```

Set target to Peter

```
obj.GetComponent<Unit> ().Target = peterObject.transform;
```

Set target to John

```
obj.GetComponent<Unit> ().Target = johnObject.transform;
```